# Who renders a django TemplateResponse if I don't?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Suppose I return a TemplateResponse object from a view in Django. Even if I don't manually call response.render() anywhere in my code, what is returned is a rendered object. Which middleware or other part of Django automatically renders TemplateResponses? I tried going through the code but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 2):

every WSGI request is handled by WSGIHandler.__call__  which is the "application" object returned by wsgi.py at setup.

```
WSGIHandler.__call__
   ->  BaseHandler -> get_response()
         -> loops through the _middleware_chain(request)   (which is setup at startup in wsgi.py-> get_wsgi_handler() 
              -> BaseHandler -> _get_response()            (for each middelware)
                  -> does all middelware stuff on the request 
                     -> excutes the view etc.
                  -> does all middelware stuff on the response
```

have a look at django/core/handlers/base.py

```
class BaseHandler:
    
   ....

    def _get_response(self, request):
        """
        Resolve and call the view, then apply view, exception, and
        template_response middleware. This method is everything that happens
        inside the request/response middleware.
        """
      
        # ... 
        # at this point "response" holds what is returned from the view


        # Complain if the view returned None (a common error).
        self.check_response(response, callback)

        # If the response supports deferred rendering, apply template
        # response middleware and then render the response
        if hasattr(response, 'render') and callable(response.render):
            for middleware_method in self._template_response_middleware:
                response = middleware_method(request, response)
                # Complain if the template response middleware returned None (a common error).
                self.check_response(
                    response,
                    middleware_method,
                    name='%s.process_template_response' % (
                        middleware_method.__self__.__class__.__name__,
                    )
                )
            try:
                response = response.render()
            except Exception as e:
                response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
                if response is None:
                    raise

        return response
```

Comment: How is this class instantiated? who calls the _get_response method on it?

Comment: @Amir You're basically asking how the entire framework works, which is really a bit too broad. Suffice it to say that if your response has a callable render method, Django will call it.